# Async call in node-webworker-threads?

Tags: node.js, web-worker

This Hello World example from the [node-webworker-threads](https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads) page works fine, and generates `Worker said: Hi ali`:

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var worker = new Worker(function(){
  postMessage("I'm working before postMessage('ali').");
  this.onmessage = function(event) {
    self.postMessage('Hi ' + event.data);
    self.close();
  };
});
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("Worker said : " + event.data);
};
worker.postMessage('ali');
```

But this does not work, and I can't figure out why.  Adding a `setTimeout` results in `self.postMessage` never getting called:

```
var Worker = require('webworker-threads').Worker;
var worker = new Worker(function(){
  postMessage("I'm working before postMessage('ali').");
  this.onmessage = function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        self.postMessage('Hi ' + event.data);
        self.close();
    },0);
  };
});
worker.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log("Worker said : " + event.data);
};
worker.postMessage('ali');
```

How are async calls handled with node-webworker-threads?

[Can someone explain the webworker-thread example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913838/can-someone-explain-the-webworker-thread-example)

Comment: great question.  `self` is a global variable, defined by webworker threads.  It's in the example itself.  I posted the entire example.  I saved it to `worker.js` and ran it as `node worker.js`

Answer (score 1):

"Workers don't have access to setTimeout, setInterval, etc.  Indeed, the HTML timer spec is not native to v8 and will need to be re-implemented in C++ level."

https://github.com/audreyt/node-webworker-threads/issues/50